Windows Key Stops Working When Connecting Second Monitor
EDIT: The issue occurs specifically with a new 21:9 ultra-wide monitor. The Windows key works for a few seconds after booting up with the monitor connected, then stops responding. There's no issue with other monitors or TV's.
I’m experiencing an issue where the Windows key stops working when I connect a second monitor to my laptop. Here’s the detailed situation:

When I boot up my laptop with only the built-in monitor, the Windows key works perfectly fine.
As soon as I connect a second monitor, the Windows key stops responding. This affects all shortcuts involving the Windows key, such as Win + R, Win + Shift + S, etc.

I have ensured that:

Both monitors are set up correctly in the display settings (extended mode).
The graphics drivers are up to date.
The keyboard is recognized properly in Device Manager.
There are no issues with the registry (no Scancode Map entry).
All Windows updates are installed.
A clean boot did not resolve the issue.
BIOS/UEFI is up to date.
Changing ports (HDMI/DisplayPort) for the second monitor did not help.
Using an external keyboard still results in the same issue.

I haven’t been able to find a solution online and would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to fix this problem.
Thank you in advance!

fyi this is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. This type of question fits better on [su]

After some troubleshooting, I discovered that the problem was related to the Dragon Center application (version 1.2.1910.3101).
Solution:
In Dragon Center, navigate to the "System Tuner" tab. There is an option to enable/disable the Windows key. Simply ensure that this option is set to "enable."
Despite never changing this setting before, it appears to have been the cause of the problem.
I hope this helps anyone experiencing a similar problem!
Thank you!
